# How to create an InputStream that acts like System.in

Tags: java

I'm trying to create a InputStream class that behaves like a System.in InputStream but can be programatically added to (an endless InputStream that can be dynamically added to)

If you have trouble understanding what I mean, here's what I have wrote and tried

```
   public class QueuedInputStream extends InputStream {

        private LinkedList<Character> list;

        public QueuedInputStream() {
            list = new LinkedList<Character>();
        }

        @Override
        public int read() throws IOException {
            while (list.isEmpty()) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            int value = (byte)list.get(0).charValue();
            list.remove();
            return value;
        }

        public void queue(String s) {
            char[] chars = s.toCharArray();
            for(int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
                list.add(chars[i]);
            }
        }

    }
```

Am I on the right track? Or am I completely wrong in trying to do this?
If you want me to explain more, feel free to ask

Comment: Have a look at PipedInputStream and ByteArrayInputStream.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[PipedInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PipedInputStream.html):

> A piped input stream should be connected to a piped output stream; the
>   piped input stream then provides whatever data bytes are written to
>   the piped output stream.

[ByteArrayInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayInputStream.html):

> A ByteArrayInputStream contains an internal buffer that contains bytes
>   that may be read from the stream.
>   (You give an array during construction, and the stream will read from it.)

Comment: Thanks, using the PipedInputStream wrapping around a PipedOutputStream, and writing to the PipedOutputStream did it

Comment: @ignis Isn't this bad practice though for a single threaded application? See the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PipedOutputStream.html).I also am trying to do what Canain was trying.

Comment: @Vance-Turner It's discouraged because `java.io` input streams [block the calling thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read()) while they wait for the data. (Note that this is the same behavior as in Canain's implementation.) What do you expect your program to do, when it tries to read from an empty pipe? A blocking piped stream is a poor choice in a single-thread scenario, of course. However, a non-blocking stream is fine. For example, it may throw an exception, or require clients to feed enough data at construction.

Answer (score 3):

Your approach has some elegance, but not around the timing logic.  You should back your stream by a `BlockingQueue` so that you don't have to do the nasty sleep.  If you call `take()` on a blocking queue, the call will block until there's input.

But there's probably utilities you can use already.  One option is to use `PipedInputStream` and `PipedOutputStream`, and then write to the `PipedOutputStream` like any other `OutputStream`.  Here's a complete example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    PipedOutputStream pipedOutputStream = new PipedOutputStream();
    final PipedInputStream in = new PipedInputStream(pipedOutputStream);

    PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(pipedOutputStream, true);

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
            try {
                for (String line; (line = reader.readLine()) != null; ) {
                    System.out.println(line);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }).start();


    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        writer.println(i);
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, your answer is similar to the first one using PipedInputStream and PipedOutputStream

Comment: @Canain: Yes, ignis got his answer in first as I was coding an example.  I posted the answer anyway in case the example helps others.